# what is best pattern or approach to handle ACL in Eloquent Models?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I'm creating a REST API using Laravel in which there is multiple parameter for an endpoint based on user's role.

Currently checking this in Services, using if conditions.

```php
class UserService
{
    public function update(array $attribute, $userId)
    {
        $userRepository = app(\App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface::class);
        $user = $userRepository->get($userId);
        $allowedUpdatableFieldForTeachers = ['name', 'age', 'graduated_at'];
        $allowedUpdatableFieldForSupervisor = ['name', 'age', 'graduated_at', 'balance', 'salary'];
        if ($user->role == 'teacher') {
            $userRepository->update(Arr::only($attribute, $allowedUpdatableFieldForTeachers), $userId);
        }
        if ($user->role == 'supervisor') {
            $userRepository->update(Arr::only($attribute, $allowedUpdatableFieldForSupervisor), $userId);
        }
    }
}
```

However its violating Single Responsibility Principle.
So whats the best practice/pattern to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SRP does not apply for all classes in your software.

For a typical class, SRP should be applied because it increases the reusability of the class. No man wants to reuse a class having two responsibilities while he only needs one. If he accepted using the class, it would be very annoying for him each time the code of the unneeded responsibility gets updated.

But for the classes at the [boundary](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of you software, SRP does not apply. This is the place where you make use of multiple typical classes, compose them in some way to handle the request from users. Normally there is no need to reuse the classes at boundary. Hence, there is no need to apply SRP to them. In other words, these classes are intended to have multiple responsibilities.

Your `UserService` class is such a place. So, don’t worry.

You can read more about SRP [here](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html). IMO, it is the best article about the principle.